# Images in plugin broken after URL migration

Tags: images, migration

I have a portfolio plugin that was part of a theme I paid for. The plugin doesn't actually show up in the plugins list of the WP admin console.

My problem is that, since doing a migration from one domain to another, the images associated with this plugin aren't showing up correctly. I wish I could tell you what the plugin is called, but I don't see a name for it. Even in the code within the theme folder. It does have some stuff in the plugin php about motopress-wrapper ?

Anyways, http://supkingston.com/gear/ is the link to the specific page I am having issues with. All the other pages seemed to have migrated fine. This one is buggy. The images don't load at first, but if you click on them, you see them? The images that aren't loading are the "featured images"

I have gone in to the media and made sure all the URL's that the images are using still work, and they do... I have also recreated some portfolio items from scratch using brand new uploaded images and it does the same thing... something is wrong with the plugin but I don't know what. Please help. I will provide as much info as I can.

**UPDATES**
I just found out that it's putting each image URL as 'http://supkingston.com/gear/' for some reason, and not actually pointing to the media

2. Thanks to your help I found the code I think. It's in a JS file called `filterable-portfolio-loop.php`

[I've uploaded the code here because it didn't copy paste well in to this editor.](http://codepen.io/frantumn/pen/wKozbM.js)

Comment: Can't help much without any code examples.

Comment: I know that's where I'm stumped. I don't even know where the plugin resides or what it's called because it was just built in to the theme / cherry framework... If I knew where the code for the plugin was, I could do a bit more.

Comment: Use a text editor like Notepad++ (Ctrl+F and "Find In FIles" tab) and do a search in all the files for `<figure class="thumbnail thumbnail__portfolio">` that's the wrapper holding the image. Posting that part here might help.

Comment: I found the code. It's here http://codepen.io/frantumn/pen/wKozbM.js lines 172 and 209